# ros Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. can not find any solution， try harder？

Tags: ubuntu, ros, apt

my ubuntu is 22.04.2lts
when i download ros-neotic-full packages i met :Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.,there are many packages missing,  so i run sudo apt install aptitude and sudo aptitude install ros-noetic-desktop-full to fix, but then it comes to this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reWhx.png)and can not find the solution(i have adopted the second solution once but it didn't work so i try again and become this) how can i solve it?

i run sudo apt install aptitude and sudo aptitude install ros-noetic-desktop-full to fix,and adopted the second solution but the picture i didn't take

Answer (score 0):

ROS Noetic is a ROS1 distro that specifically targets Ubuntu 20.04. If you're set on using 22.04 you need to use [ROS2 Humble](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Releases/Release-Humble-Hawksbill.html). Otherwise you'll need to downgrade to 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

adding to the previous answer, consider using [docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/ros/) to avoid downgrading from your current ubuntu distro or using ROS2 if your not familiar with it.